# Intellij Koltin/java Property name 'désactivé' may contain only letters and digits

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, utf-8, internationalization, intellij-inspections

I try to use accented characters for variable names but intellij doesn't really like it
this does not pose a problem when compiling or even when using... after some testing

I started by managing the first warning Non-ASCII character

[image]

here is an example (koltin code)

```
data class Utilisateur(
    var idUtilisateur: UUID?,
    var nom: String?,
    var désactivé: Boolean?, // Property name 'désactivé' may contain only letters and digits 
)
```

I also tried this but without success
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you do not use non-ASCII characters in identifiers, as it makes it easier for people who can't type those letters to collaborate.

That said, if you don't want any warnings for this, in addition to the "Non-ASCII characters" you already disabled, you need to disable/edit the "Naming Conventions" inspections under the "Kotlin" disclosure group.

[image]

Note that there are separate inspections for separate program elements. To remove the warning, you can either disable them, or edit the regex in the options section:

[image]

Comment: Is this a bug in IntelliJ's inspections, or does it say anywhere in the Kotlin Coding Conventions that you shouldn't use non-ASCII characters for property names? All I can find is "[Names of functions, properties and local variables start with a lowercase letter and use the camel case and no underscores](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#function-names)" and `'é'.isLowerCase()` returns true, so by that guideline an "é" in a variable name should be ok.

Comment: @k314159 I haven't been able to find a bug report for it, and either way, *not* allowing non-ASCII names should be encouraged IMO, as it makes it easier for people who can't type those letters to collaborate.

Comment: @k314159 interpreting "lowercase" as literally `isLowerCase()` leads to some questionable conclusions. Hangul, Hiragana, Katakana and CJK ideographs are also considered "not lowercase" by `isLowerCase()`, so by that logic, I cannot write identifier names in Chinese, Japanese or Korean, but I can in Greek or Russian? That doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: @Sweeper Could you add that reasoning (for recommending against using non-ASCII characters in identifiers) into the answer?  (I disagreed with that recommendation until I saw your comment — I'm not 100% certain I agree even now, but it's a good reason!)

Comment: @gidds Edited. That's interesting. I totally thought everyone would agree.

Comment: @Sweeper My initial thoughts were: why _shouldn't_ people be able to use identifiers that are natural to them and/or to the problem domain?  Isn't it a bit bigoted to assume that everyone speaks only basic ASCII?  The almost universal adoption of Unicode is solving many traditional character-set- and language-related problems; shouldn't coding reap the benefit of that too?  (And if any such issues _do_ remain in Kotlin, then the more people that hit them, the quicker they'll be found and fixed.) (contd…)

Comment: …But, as you say, _entering_ non-ASCII is awkward for many, which is a good counter-argument.  (Another might be that using a common language eases collaboration — and since Kotlin's keyword, libraries, and documentation are all in English, then you'd expect Kotlin developers to have a basic working knowledge of English, making it a natural choice.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your prompt response
I will take the risk for this project of using accentuated characters
for those who want here is how I did it

```
\p{Ll}\p{L}*\d*
```

[image]

[image]